# Upload app on AppStore developed with QuickConnect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, app-store

I want to know if an app developed with [QuickConnect](http://www.quickconnectfamily.org/), and uploaded on AppStore will be approved by Apple successfully or will there be any specific terms and conditions for this type of app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "an app developed by quick time"?

Comment: @GarlicFries: sorry its typing mistake, actually its QuickConnect.

Comment: This question is a great fit for [the App Stores Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple used to have a policy banning apps that were not written on C,Objective-C, or C++. Tha policy has long since changed. So long as your app is completely compiled and does not include any language runtime or interpreters, you should be fine. The reason to be concerned is section 2.8 of [the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (Login required), which states:

> **2.8** Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

That said, it doesn't sound like you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with QuickConnect in particular, but other projects that build "native-ish" apps by wrapping web applications in a UIWebView (PhoneGap and Appcelerator being the best known of these) have had no problem getting approved for the App Store. I bet you'll do fine.